# Como puedo visualizar correctamente un link en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, enlace

tengo que analizar distintos mensajes que provienen de una API y en caso de contener un link, procesar el mismo y mostrarlo en una etiqueta . Les muestro el codigo de la funcion que utilizo.

```
    function urlText(text) {
        var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
        const newText = text.replace(urlRegex, function (url) {
            return <a target='_blank' href={url}>{url}</a>
        })
        return newText
    }
```

a esta funcion la llamo en una etiqueta

el problema esta que cuando renderiza el componente obtengo este reusltado:

supongamos que el texto es el siguiente:

https://www.youtube.com/ este es un texto de pruebas

lo que renderiza el componente luego de ejecutar la funcion urlText es lo siguiente:

```
<a target='_blank' href={url}>{url}</a> this is a text message
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que te renderiza supongo que es:

`[object Object] este es un texto de pruebas`

Esto pasa porque con `text.replace(...` reemplazas un texto por un objeto y javascript intenta comvertir el objecto (`<a target='_blank' ...`) en texto. Como no sabe como hacerlo te devuelve `[object Object]`. Por lo tanto el primer paso será hacer que la función `urlText` devuelva el texto correctamente procesado:

```js
function urlText(text) {
  var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
  const newText = text.replace(urlRegex, function (url) {
      return `<a target='_blank' href=${url}>${url}</a>`
  })
  return newText
}
```

Luego podrás renderizarlo, pero utilizando `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` para poder cargar HTML directamente en react:

```js
function urlText(text) {
  var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
  const newText = text.replace(urlRegex, function (url) {
      return `<a target='_blank' href=${url}>${url}</a>`
  })
  return newText
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: urlText('https://www.youtube.com/ este es un texto de pruebas')}}
  />
  , 
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```